# Kotlin reduce operator seems to not work

Tags: kotlin

Tried to run this example on Kotlin's online learning tool:

```
fun toJSON(collection: Collection<Int>): String {
    val str = collection.reduce{ a:String, b:Int -> ""}
    return str.toString()
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to compile, spitting this error:

`Error:(2, 25) Type parameter bound for T in inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(operation: (S, T) -> S): S
is not satisfied: inferred type Int is not a subtype of String`

Anyone seen this?...not sure if it's an error with the online tool or if it's actually something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `reduce` a collection of ints to a collection of strings. These compile:

```
// reduce to int
collection.reduce { x:Int, y:Int -> 0 }

// map to string first, then reduce
collection.map { "" }.reduce { x:String, y:String -> "" }
```

This is clearer if you take a look at the `reduce` signature:

`fun <S, T: S> Iterable<T>.reduce(operation: (S, T) -> S): S`

It basically operates on a collection of type `T`, and produces an `S` which is a `T` or a supertype of `T`.

Answer (score 8):

The [Kotlin Standard Library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) has two different types of accumulators: `fold` and `reduce`. It looks like you want [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

```
collection.fold(initial = "") { accumulator: String, element: Int -> "" }
```